# How to replace the first few bytes of a file in Ruby without opening the whole file?

Tags: ruby

I have a 30MB XML file that contains some gibberish in the beginning, and so typically I have to remove that in order for Nokogiri to be able to parse the XML document properly.

Here's what I currently have:

```
    contents = File.open(file_path).read
    if contents[0..123].include? 'authenticate_response'
      fixed_contents = File.open(file_path).read[123..-1]
      File.open(file_path, 'w') { |f| f.write(fixed_contents) }
    end
```

However, this actually causes the ruby script to open up the large XML file twice. Once to read the first 123 characters, and another time to read everything but the first 123 characters.

To solve the first issue, I was able to accomplish this:

```
contents = File.open(file_path).read(123)
```

However, now I need to remove these characters from the file without reading the entire file. How can I "trim" the beginning of this file without having to open the entire thing in memory?

Comment: "replace" is very different from "remove". You can't do the latter without reading the whole file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can open the file once, then read and check the "garbage" and finally pass the opened file directly to nokogiri for parsing. That way, you only need read the file once and don't need to write it at all.

```
File.open(file_path) do |xml_file|
  if xml_file.read(123).include? 'authenticate_response'
    # header found, nothing to do
  else
    # no header found. We rewind and let nokogiri parse the whole file
    xml_file.rewind
  end

  xml = Nokogiri::XML.parse(xml_file)
  # Now to whatever you want with the parsed XML document
end
```

Please refer to the documentation of [`IO#read`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html#method-i-read), [`IO#rewind`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html#method-i-rewind) and [`Nokigiri::XML::Document.parse`](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri%2FXML%2FDocument.parse) for details about those methods.

Comment: You should consider adding `begin ... ensure; xml_file.close; end`.

Comment: I updated the answer to use the block variant of `File.open`. However, even without this, the file would be implicitly closed on next garbage collection.

Comment: @HolgerJust what would lead you to believe this would be GCed?

Comment: @engineersmnky: Because in the original version of my answer, the file object was assigned to a local variable which would go out of scope as soon as the execution returns from the method the code is in. After that, the file object will be garbage collected and the file closed.

Comment: @HolgerJust I guess that is extremely dependent since the OP and your original answer technically operate in the global scope of `main` so this file will remain open until the program itself terminates.

Comment: @engineersmnky If someone were to actually implement a long-running program / script by putting this into the `main` context in a way where this would make any difference (which would be against any best-practice to structuring code in Ruby since about forever), yes, this might have been a leak. Still, (1) this a very constructed scenario and (2) my current answer is safe even from this theoretical issue.